# DataGridColumn dynamic(parametric) binding to a column of a collection

Tags: wpf, binding, datagridcolumn

I'm trying to bind a datagrid to a collection, but I do not know which are the columns of the collection.
So I try to to bind the column to a property that is passed to the view.

my code is:

```
  <FrameworkElement x:Key="ProxyElement" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_VMItemSelector}"/>
```

```
<WPFCtrlDg:SelfBindingDataGrid x:Name="_sbdgAvailableItems" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Availables}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentAvailableItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    IsReadOnly="{Binding DataContext.IsReadOnly,
                    Source={StaticResource ProxyElement},
                    Mode=OneWay}">
            <WPFCtrlDg:SelfBindingDataGrid.Columns>
                <WPFCtrlDg:ExtDataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding DataContext.DetailBinding,
                                                          Source={StaticResource ProxyElement},
                                                          Mode=OneWay}"  
                                                          Tag="CD_FUNCTION" 
                                                          Visibility="Hidden"/>
                <WPFCtrlDg:ExtDataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding DataContext.RightColumnHeader,
                                                          Source={StaticResource ProxyElement},
                                                          Mode=OneWay}"  
                                                          Binding="{Binding DataContext.RightColumnHeader,
                                                          Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}, 
                                                          Mode=OneWay}" 
                                                          Width="*"/>
```

and in the view I have

```
    private string _rightColumnHeader;
    public string RightColumnHeader
    {
        get { return _rightColumnHeader; }
        set { _rightColumnHeader = value; }
    }
```

the value is set to "DS_FUNCTION" which is a filed of the collection I bind, but what I see in the dataGrid is alwats "DS_FUNTION" for each element of the collection.

Comment: Can you not just set the `DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns` property to `true`?

Comment: No, I need also some logic for adding rows from one grid to this one and viceversa and other tasks. In addition I do not want to display all the colomns and the collection type can change (I want to create a wpf reusable component)

Comment: Where is your `RightColumnHeader` property defined?

Comment: in the xaml.cs of the view.

Comment: Then that is why it appears the same in every row. You need to move that into the class definition of the type of object that is inside your collection if you want to have a different value displayed for each item.

Comment: I know, but I fave to make it a property of my component, so that I can bind this property when I insert my new component in a UI to use it. that's why I'm doing all this.